# Inserting Visio diagrams in a pdf file

Tags: pdf, microsoft-visio

Well, the question title is pretty self-explanatory but still;

> **How do I insert Visio diagrams in a pdf file?**

I've tried googling it but I've only encountered ways to do the other way round, that is, I've only found ways of inserting pdf files into Visio diagrams.

Anybody know of any ways to do this?

---

Additional details following doenoe's query:

> I need to add the Visio diagram to an existing pdf file: it can be as attachment such that when I open my pdf document and click on "attachments " navigation pane, I can view my Visio diagram from within the pdf itself; even if someone doesn't have Visio installed they must still be able to view the diagram.

Comment: How do you mean insert visio diagram in a pdf file? 
Do you want specific diagrams to be inserted or a complete visio file to be converted to pdf?

Comment: I need to add the Visio diagram to an existing pdf file: it can be as attachment such that when I open my pdf document and click on "attachments " navigation pane, I can view my Visio diagram from within the pdf itself, even if someone doesn't have Visio installed they can still view the diagram.

Comment: Usually you should have a master document from which you create the pdf. In that document I suppose that you can insert your visio diagram. Else if you have a program that is able to handle pdf files you can insert it directly or  you can print your diagram as scalable format (or in fixed one with high enough resolution) and insert it inside as a normal figure.

Comment: There is no way to insert a Visio document, specifically, into a PDF. Your best bet is to convert the document to an image (by changing the file type in Save As) and then insert that image into your PDF.

Comment: @BrianDuddy If I save the Visio diagram as a pdf file, can I insert it into another pdf file then?

Comment: Yes, the free version of [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) should allow you to do this, as will paid PDF editors such as Adobe Acrobat, Foxit PhantomPDF, etc.